# Can I, as a user, change the default chmod settings for my account?

Tags: linux, chmod

I work in a shared computing environment and the default setting is r-x for group and others; it's upto the users to change this. I can chmod and change the permissions for all the files. However any new files created all have the default permissions. Is there anyway to change that so that I don't have to chmod everytime or run chmod as a cronjob?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is called the [`umask`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/umask), and that's also the name of the command that changes it.  To make a persistent change, add a `umask` command to your shell startup file -- probably named `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, in your home directory; if you don't seem to have any such file, post the output of these commands:

```
$ grep $LOGNAME /etc/passwd
$ (cd; ls -ld .??*)
```

Comment: For example: `umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=` sets the default settings to 0770.